# How to delete the first digit number in PHP

Tags: php, regex, laravel, preg-replace, regex-negation

I have a data of phone number starts with +63 and 09

for example the user insert 09123456789 then save. The user shouldn't success if he enters +639123456789 because it was same number at all.

I tried using substr_replace

```
$data3 = substr_replace("+63", "0",0, 3);
```

is there other option? i think the substr_replace will have error in the future.

thanks

Comment: try `str_replace('+63','0')`

Comment: `substr_replace` is probably a safer option than `str_replace`

Comment: I don't see the problem you are trying to solve. As I see it this question is off topic on SO. It could probably be posted on code review though

Comment: Those things are already solved. I would suggest using [intl-tel-input](https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input) on frontend and [libphonenumber-for-php](https://github.com/giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php) on backend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `+63` must be at the start, you may use a `preg_replace` like

```
$s = preg_replace('~^\+63~', '0', $s);
```

Here,

- `^` - start of a string position
- `\+` - a literal `+`
- `63` - a `63` substring.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6TZaQX/1) and a [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/5G2Wm).

Please **also consider** [Tpojka's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56270131/how-to-delete-the-first-digit-number-in-php/56270185#comment99158571_56270131) to use a combination of [intl-tel-input](https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input) on front-end and [libphonenumber-for-php](https://github.com/giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php) on back-end if you need to sanitize and validate international phone numbers.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can have a condition to check and have `str_replace`

if there is a `+` on your request then make remove the first 3 letters including `+`

```
if (substr($phone, 0, 1) == '+') {
    $phone = str_replace(substr($phone, 0, 3), '0', $phone);
}

$phone_number = $phone;
```